# Fetch only tasks with a certain value

Tags: swift, predicate, cloudkit

I'm making a to do app that has tasks for specific teams using CloudKit as my backend. I've set it up so that the first screen you see is the teams list. When you select the team, I want to just see all the tasks related to that specific team. I've gotten the app to save and fetch tasks but all of the tasks appear under every team.

I am very new to CloudKit (I used Parse before) and also new to predicates. Currently I am passing the team recordID as a string using the `prepareForSegue` function to my Tasks View Controller. In Parse, that was all I needed to get just the tasks for that team. I can see that the saving is working correctly when I look at CloudKit Dashboard (every task has the correct team recordID in its record).

I know the problem is somewhere in the next bit of code but I am unsure of how to go about doing it.

```
func loadTasks() {
        tasks = [CKRecord]()
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Tasks", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil))
        publicData.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (results:[CKRecord]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if let tasks = results {
                self.tasks = tasks
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }


        self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
    }
```

So I think I'm asking how to use predicates to filter the data to only show the tasks for the selected team. I only have what I have currently because I followed a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the current predicate, use something along the lines of:

```
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "team == %@", team)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Tasks", predicate: predicate)
```

Where team is the relevant team, which is likely to be a CKReference.

Answer (score 1):

Michael,

A predicate is like a regular expression. Are you familiar with regular expressions? If you are, then you find predicates a piece of cake.

All your saying here is I want to you to return all the records you have in the "Tasks" database in which the team field equals the value in the team variable.

Your name sake Michael answered the question; in honestly he deserves some kudos here.

Hope this short explanation helps!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I don't quite understand it still but it works. If someone is willing to explain this, I would be grateful.

```
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Tasks", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "team==%@", self.team))
```